# How configure time zone in MariaDB Azure?

Tags: azure, timezone, mariadb

How can I change the time zone in the configuration of my maria DB?
I can put hours directly but in my case as there are 2 time changes during the year I would have to change it each time.
Is there any way I can put the time zone instead of the time difference?

[image]

It says here that it can't be done, but I don't know if this problem has already been solved.

[Configure time zones on MySQL Database on Azure](https://docs.azure.cn/en-us/mysql-database-on-azure/mysql-database-timezone-config)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The doc page you linked to is outdated.  Please refer to [*Working with the time zone parameter*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/mariadb/howto-server-parameters#working-with-the-time-zone-parameter) instead.

Specifically:

- Populate the time zone tables with the command:

  ```
  CALL mysql.az_load_timezone();
  ```
- Then you can set the `time_zone` global parameter to a named time zone from [the list of IANA time zone names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones), such as `Europe/Madrid`.